# JavaScript module not working in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, module

I am having trouble with my JavaScript module in the Edge browser. In Chrome everything works perfectly. Since my users have both Edge and Chrome available to them, the application has to work in both.

I asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610984/javascript-module-not-working-in-edge-version-44-make-18-17763) earlier, but I failed to to provide enough code to reproduce the problem. I have now made this pen https://codepen.io/johannes1/pen/GRjBpxz, that works in Chrome but not in Edge.

In my header I have:

```
<script type="module" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

It is my understanding that ES6 modules work in Edge and chrome alike, so the mistake has to be mine, but I cannot find it. I am really stuck and would very much appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge only supports ES6 modules in version 79 (Jan 2020) or newer.

Since Edge releases are tied to major updates to Windows 10, it is easy to get stuck on an old version.

In general I recommend that Windows users make it a point to check Windows Update for prompts to install upgrades to the OS, but that doesn't help much from the typical developer's point of view.

If you need to support old versions of Edge, then use Webpack (or one of its rivals like rollup) to bundle your modules instead of relying on browser support for them.